# Constructor and anonymous union with const members

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, unions

Is it possible to have an anonymous union with const members? I have the following:

```
struct Bar {
  union {
    struct { const int x, y; };
    const int xy[2];
  };
  Bar() : x(1), y(2) {}
};
```

With G++ 4.5 I get the error:

```
error: uninitialized member ‘Bar::<anonymous union>::xy’ with ‘const’ type ‘const int [2]’
```

Comment: `struct { const int x, y; };` is not valid C++. Are you asking whether you can do something with GCC?

Comment: Why is it not valid? Does it need a constructor with an initialisation list?

Comment: The GCC -pedantic switch seems useful. "ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs" it says. If I remove the `const`s above, I get the same warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a problem in GCC that was fixed in version 4.6. Your code now works fine.

It still depends on a GCC extension because it uses an anonymous struct, but most compilers support them now. Also, the following code now builds properly with `-pedantic`:

```
struct Bar {
  union {
    const int x;
    const int y;
  };
  Bar() : x(1) {}
};
```

That code is also accepted by Clang and Visual Studio 2010 (but fails with 2008).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Its possible but you've to initialized it when its constructed. You cannot leave it uninitialized. But in this particular case, I don't think its possible, since you cannot initialize an array in the initialization-list.

By the way, have a look at this interesting topic:

- [An union with a const and a nonconst member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653471/an-union-with-a-const-and-a-nonconst-member)

Answer (score 0):

No. Try using GCC's -pedantic switch:

```
  warning: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs
```

The example is therefore also illegal with the `const`s removed.

Comment: I am afraid this does not answer the question. Anonymous structs are forbidden, but not anonymous unions.

Comment: @SamHocevar Thankyou! I appreciate your contribution, but surely the answer is technically still no: I was looking for legal C++.

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question, then? It states _“Is it possible to have an anonymous union with const members“_ to which the answer appears to be yes. You seem to have a different problem with anonymous `struct`s.